# Optimized table in Latex Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment

I want to optimize table in beamer to look beautiful by centring their cells and fix its \hline in the first line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}
 \date{Mohcine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{optimized the following table}
\begin{block}{~\vspace{0.7cm}}
\begin{center}
\vspace{-0.8cm}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
 \textcolor{white}{\bf discriminant  $\Delta=b^{2}-4ac$} & \textcolor{white}{\bf set of roots} \\\midskip\hline
$\Delta >0$       & $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a},\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \right\}$\\ \hline   
$\Delta=0$        & $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b}{2a} \right\}$  \\ \hline
$\Delta<0$        &   $S=\emptyset$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tell me how it looks or I'll eliminate the answer.

Comment: It's looks great but could you just center the word in cell 'set of root'

Comment: The actual answer of Bernard is very good instead of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this improvement with a vertical centring of the cells, with the `\setcellgapes` command from `makecell` , which adds a fixed vertical space at the top and bottom of cells. Unrelated to the spacing problem: I  replaced `\emptyset` which I don't like with the nicer `\varnothing`.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}
 \date{Mohcine}
 \usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{optimized the following table}
\begin{block}{~\vspace{0.7cm}}
\begin{center}
\vspace{-0.8cm}
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{0.45\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.45\textwidth}}
 \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\boldmath discriminant $\Delta=b^{2}-4ac$} & \textcolor{white}{\bfseries set of roots} \\
$\Delta >0$ & $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a},\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \right\}$\\ \hline
$\Delta=0$ & $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b}{2a} \right\}$ \\ \hline
$\Delta<0$ & $S=\varnothing$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not expert in tables :-) +1..and with lot of sincerity I not like very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You don't like tables with some vertical padding??

Comment: No no: in general I not see the questions with the tables :-). Have you understood me? :-)

Comment: I've got you! I'm a bit slow by these times of coronæ virorum ;o)

Answer (score 5):

I will use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}`, I will fix the name madrid with Madrid and the value of `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\date{Mohcine}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{optimized the following table}
\begin{block}{~\vspace{0.8cm}}
\begin{center}
\vspace{-1.13cm}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.45\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.45\textwidth}}
 \textcolor{white}{\bf discriminant  $\Delta=b^{2}-4ac$} & \textcolor{white}{\bf set of roots} \\[1ex]\hline
$\Delta >0$       & $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a},\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \right\}$\\ \hline   
$\Delta=0$        & $S=\left\{ -\dfrac{b}{2a} \right\}$  \\ \hline
$\Delta<0$        &   $S=\emptyset$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: s]

Comment: +1 upvote but could you center also 'set of root'

Comment: @Educ Don't worry for the upvotes :-)...see the final result :-)....I'm not the table specialist

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\date{Mohcine}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cellspace,tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{C}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{tctabularx}[1]{%
          enhanced,
          fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small\sffamily,
          colback=blue!10, colframe=blue,
          #1,
          before upper app={\rowcolor{blue!60}},
                            }% end tctabularx

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
\frametitle{Optimized the following table}
\tcbset{width=0.85\linewidth}
    \begin{tctabularx}{tabularx={C|SC}}
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{discriminant} $\Delta=b^{2}-4ac$} 
        & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{set of roots}} \\
$\Delta>0$ &    %\smallskip
                $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a},\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \right\}$                
                %\smallskip  
                \\ \hline
$\Delta=0$ & $S=\left\{ \dfrac{-b}{2a} \right\}$ \\ \hline
$\Delta<0$ & $S=\varnothing$    \\
    \end{tctabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```